# j-query and javascript form using multiple submits not submitting all data from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I'm not hugely good with javascript or jQuery, mainly dealing with databases, but I've been having a little trouble getting a rather complex form to submit all its data.

Basically it amounts to three different submit buttons which are meant to post the data in the form with a different privacy setting sent to the table. The table in the database is being updated with the correct privacy setting for each button, but it isn't sending a value for the thought part of the form to the php file it is meant to.

The form is implemented in the HTML as follows:

```
<FORM action="thought_post.php" method="post" name="thought">

<INPUT onfocus="this.select(); this.value=''" 
       type="text" value="Thought..." 
       size="72" />
<div class="megamenu" style="position: absolute; ;left: 478px; top: 11px;">
    <ul>
        <li class="downservices"><a href="#">Publish...</a></li>
        <div class="servicesdropped">
            <ul class="right">
                <input type="hidden" name="privacy">
                <li><a href="javascript:poststyle('private')">Private</a></li> 
                <li><a href="javascript:poststyle('friends')">Friends only</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:poststyle('public')">Public</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>

</FORM>
```

and the javascript in the header of the same page is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dropdown.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".downservices").click(function(){
            $(".servicesdropped").toggle("fast");
        });
    });
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
   function poststyle(selectedtype)
    {
       document.thought.privacy.value = selectedtype ;
       document.thought.submit() ;
    }
-->
</script>
```

If anyone could explain why the `thought` value entered by the user isn't being passed to `thought_post.php` that would be wonderful!

Comment: If you're using JQuery there is absolutely NO reason to have in-line javascript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assigning a `name` to your "thought" `input`.  `name` is required for a form control to be [valid for submission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls):

```
<INPUT onfocus="this.select(); this.value=''" type="text" value="Thought..." size="72" name="thought" />
```

As a side note, make sure your other `input` is valid markup as well, `input` tags should be self closing:

```
<input type="hidden" name="privacy" />
```

After making these changes and inspecting the form post with [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/), I could see the correct value for "thought" go through.

Additionally, as the other answer mentions, you should [separate your JavaScript and HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_Javascript) and maybe accomplish this completely with jQuery.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an id for the privacy field (like, say, id="privacy") and selecting it with this:

```
getElementById("privacy").value = selectedtype;
```

By the way, you can put all the javascript in one `<script>` block:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".downservices").click(function(){
            $(".servicesdropped").toggle("fast");
        });
    });

    function poststyle(selectedtype)
    {
        document.thought.privacy.value = selectedtype ;
        document.thought.submit() ;
    }
</script>
```

You could also very easily handle the focus event on your input with jQuery so the scripting isn't down in your HTML.